# Does it make sense to normalize?

Tags: normalization

My data consists of multiple NHL seasons where the total number of goals scored by each player is kept track.

I intend to compare the distribution of goals scored between each season.

My thinking is that I need to normalize goals scored before I can properly compare distributions since not every season has had the same number of games played.

Is it in fact necessary to normalize the data in order to fairly compare the distributions?

Comment: Welcome to Data Science.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's look at the term [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)).

> In statistics and applications of statistics, normalization can have a range of meanings. In the simplest cases, normalization of ratings means adjusting values measured on different scales to a notionally common scale, often prior to averaging. In more complicated cases, normalization may refer to more sophisticated adjustments where the intention is to bring the entire probability distributions of adjusted values into alignment.

Your NHL goals example probably does not need "adjusting values measured on different scales to a notionally common scale."

Think of the handful of players who had a high-scoring beginning of the season, and then was injured and sat out the majority of games. Would you want to normalize his goals up proportionally to the rest of the league?